# Mixed-effects model for asymmetry

Tags: anova, linear-model

I am working with a set of data where each individual has a continuous measurement for the left and right side of the body. I am interested in whether or not side has an effect on the measurement.

Would it be appropriate to use a mixed effects model where the 'measurement' is the response variable, 'side' the fixed variable, and 'ID' (individual) the random variable?

Edited:
The subject is an actual person. The measurement is homologous: it is the same for the left and right side of the body. The actual measurement is taken in millimeters.

Comment: what is the subject  of measured variable?  What  is it that  gives you a measurement for an individual. The data  if any?

Comment: please state reason for generating the data.

Comment: @subhashc.davar See the edit above. The measurements are taken by a single researcher. The reason for generating the data is to see if there is asymmetry between the homologous measurements.

Comment: Could you tell us which other variables you have which could be used in a regression model?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen There are multiple types of measurements. I was planning on using one model per measurement. There is also demographic information: age, sex, and population.

Comment: Its OK with separate models for the separate responses. So then the covariables are the demogrphics, or also others?  How much does the measurement differ? Allpersons are adults, all childreb, mixed? Is it narural to compare by differencing or by ratios?___ the latest could indicate use of logs.  Do you have so e genetal size (height, weight,) as covariables?

Comment: All of them are adults. Other studies have shown there is little if any difference in the difference (left-right) between populations and sex. The one population that shows a difference is not included in my data. That is why I was not planning on including those. However, if you look for a difference in pure measurement between populations it does exist, it just doesn't exist when looking at the difference between left-right measurements. Not sure if that would alter how to approach this or not.

Comment: The only other variables I have available are stature, age (all adults with adult morphology), sex, and population (white/black).

Comment: Using the model as I've written in the question does appear to be working. There are three particular measurements that I suspect have a larger amount of asymmetry than others. Those three are showing up as statistically significant while the others are not.

Comment: I think the model you have described looks appropriate!

Comment: Something which could be usefull:  You can make a plot of `Diff` versus `Mean` of the two sides, maybe also as a conditioning plot with some covariable as conditioning variable.  Maybe you could include such a plot in the post  (This is sometimes called "Tukey mean-difference plot")

Comment: You have given a lot of extra information in comments, please add that as part of the original post.